# Changing cost matrix has no effect on weka results

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

Thanks in advance for the help.

I am trying to train a binary classifier on a dataset containing about 10000 samples.  This dataset is imbalanced with a ratio between the two classes of about 1:9.  I would like to increase the cost of misclassification of the lower occurring class but no matter what method I use, nor what cost matrix I use, I get the same results (basically the output of a zeroR model).  I would expect to see at least some difference for different cost matrices when using logistic regression which has not been the case.  I am using weka 3-7-11.  I have noticed that only libLinear (not a stock classifier) gives predictions that are significantly different from zeroR.  I have not noticed this with libSVM.  This seems very weird to me.  What might be going on?

Comment: Frankly? Weka may state that it has that feature but it may not be implemented. I kinda loath this tool - I had to use it a lot and I've read lot's of it's source, and it is full of unused variables, empty catch blocks, etc.

Comment: That's possible, but I don't think so.  I've used it before.  I do agree with you though about the implementation.  I usually use matlab or R.  weka is nice for the quick and dirty approach though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out what was going on.  @FilipMalczak was partially correct.  You cannot use the cost matrix tool under the "More Options" button; it doesn't work. Instead, you have to pick meta/CostSensitiveClassify as your classifier and then within the options for this (reached by clicking on the name of the classifier; not within the pulldown menu mind you) assign the cost matrix and actual classifier you want.